# Clearcase Server storage location lsstgloc returns nothing from network desktop

Tags: location, view, storage, clearcase

On the clearcase (v7.1.2) server when we run the cleartool lsstgloc command we get back entried for Views and Vobs in the format
VIEWS   \servername\clearcase_storage\views
VOBS    \servername\clearcase_storage\vobs
But when i run the same command on the network desktop with Clearcase full client installed and pointing at that same server the lsstgloc command returns nothing.
Both the desktop and Clearcase Server are windows boxes. Both on the same domain and both point to the same Region called windows_registry_region
The Storage locations on the server are shared as when i try and map a drive on the windows desktop to them I can see the folders.

When i try to create a new view via the client on the desktop when i look at the "Advanced Properties" window of the view creation the user server storage location is empty and greyed out.
If i create a view via the client installed onto the Server all is okay.

Any ideas.

Comment: What does return a `cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview` when you create a view locally? (command to run within the created view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you see this behavior when the two hosts are in different regions or the global path to the storage location is mapped differently.  E.G. the path to reach the same destination is different between the two hosts.